# How to install Epson Perfection V600 Photo Scanner drivers?

Tags: scanner, epson

I installed the driver for [Epson Perfection V600 Photo](https://epson.com/Support/Scanners/Perfection-Series/Epson-Perfection-V600-Photo/s/SPT_B11B198011?review-filter=Linux): `iscan-data_1.13.0-1all.deb` as well as `iscan_2.28.1-3.ltdl7_i386.deb`.

But the scanner does not work. How can I install the scanner drivers?

Answer (score 7):

### Driver install steps for older Ubuntu (<= 14.04)

---

***Note***: See my other answer for latest Ubuntu steps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1135180/8570

---

Looks like a package is missing but I will detail the whole process to help other users.

**Search** for the [Epson Driver site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/) for `Perfection V600` Linux drivers:

[image]

**Download** the relevant packages from both links:

`iscan-data_1.24.0-2_all.deb`

`iscan_2.29.2-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb`

`iscan-plugin-gt-x820_2.2.0-1_amd64.deb`

*Notes:*

- For Ubuntu 8.04 and lower download `ltdl3` instead of `ltdl7`
- For 32-bit Ubuntu users download `i386` instead of `amd64`

**Install** the packages as per the order above by double-clicking on the package to open it with the Ubuntu Software Centre. Alternatively use `dpkg -i <deb>` from the terminal for each package.

**Connect** and power on the scanner.

**Open** `Dash` and search for `Image Scan! for Linux`

It sometimes can take a while for the software to open, so be patient, and eventually it should find your scanner and you are ready to scan.

*References*:

- [Epson Scanner FAQ](http://download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/scanner.html)
- [Epson Scanner Manual](http://support.epson.ru/upload/library_file/11/scanner_linux.pdf%E2%80%8E)

Comment: perfect, it still works on Ubuntu 16.04 / Linux Mint 18.1 :)  now they are packaging tar.gz containing all necessary. There is install.sh which will do everything (just few dpkg --install there). Works perfectly, the scanner colors are nice (scans also vivid pink which HP scans as grey).

Answer (score 5):

## Driver install steps for Ubuntu 17.10 onwards

Epson released an updated combined install package which can be obtained via their support site.

### Download

[**Espon Driver Search**](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult)

Search for `V600`, choose `Linux` operating system and downloading *all-in-one* driver package.

[image: v600_result]

### Install

Epson provide notes on how to install but the quick overview is to run the following in the terminal that will extract and start the installation process:

```
tar xf iscan-gt-x820-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb.tar.gz
cd iscan-gt-x820-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb
./install.sh
```

### Additional steps

Normally this would be enough but at the time of writing *April 2019* iScan opens with this error message:

```
Could not send command to scanner. Check the scanner’s status.
```

So additional steps are required. These have been taken from [bug #1728012](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012).

#### Fix Epson USB device permission

Create a rules file so that the USB scanner has permission to be used by user without needing `sudo`.

```
sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/79-udev-epson.rules
```

Paste this line into the new rules file:

```
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="EPSON", DRIVERS=="usb", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="*", MODE="0777"
```

#### Fix libsane-epkowa driver location

As mentioned in the bug report the libsane-epkowa drivers are not being found so create a link to them in the correct location:

```
sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
```

### Troubleshooting

Some commands to check if your scanner can be found. I have included the output with working Epson V600 scanner.

Check if your scanner device can be found:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `epkowa:interpreter:001:010' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
```

Find any scanner attached to the computer (without superuser privileges). To identify USB permission issues.

```
$ sane-find-scanner
could not open USB device ...
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x013a [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:001:010
could not open USB device ...
```

with superuser privileges

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x013a [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:001:010
```

Comment: Is the Digital ICE option also available under Linux?

Comment: A [Unix SE Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228821/8443) suggests the driver is capable. However will need commercial VueScan (test it for free) which has the software capability for infrared dust removal.

Comment: Here's a direct download link to the drivers, rather than using the search, if you have a V600/GT-X820 http://support.epson.net/linux/en/epsonscan2.php

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 18.04 you can install Epson Perfection V600 Photo scanner (tested that works on January 2023). This is an all-in-one software for Linux, released on December 2022 by Epson. You can download `epsonscan2-bundle-6.7.0.0.x86_64.deb.tar.gz` from here: https://support.epson.net/linux/en/epsonscan2.php

This gets installed without issues, however all color scans are dominated by a bright green overlay. The older all-in-one software, `iscan-gt-x820-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz` (available from here:https://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-x820&version=2.30.4) gets installed and works without issue.

If the `iscan` options to save the scanned file as a `.png` or `.jpeg` are greyed out, install `libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb` from this site: [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/15108504](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/15108504), if you have issues with `.png` files, and `libjpeg62` if you have issues for `.jpeg` files.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I decided to give Epson Scan2 a shot, and like it much better than Epson Image Scan. FYI, this post mentioned Ubuntu 18.04 specifically, and I just wanted to confirm that it works on 20.04 also, in case anyone happens to come across this like I did.

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 23.10

You need to go to the [EPSON Download Center](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule), search for your model and download the driver.

The drivers depend on `libsane`. However, in Ubuntu 23.10, the package `libsane` is missing. A workaround is to download and install the `libsane` package from another Ubuntu release. In the example below, I am using [`libsane` from Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/libsane) for `amd64` architecture. You also have to install `libsane1` package, because `libsane` depends on it.

```
sudo apt install libsane1
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sane-backends/libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb
```

After that, you should be able to install your drivers with Running `sudo ./install.sh` from within the driver's directory.

#### Related:

- [Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic: Unable to locate package libsane](https://askubuntu.com/a/1493881/1157209)