# Device driver for Epson V600 Perfection

Tags: drivers, scanner

I have downloaded Epson's iscan-bundle-1.0.0-x64.deb and run 
sudo ./install.sh.  The script runs without errors.  However, the device driver does not get installed.  As a test I ran Simple Scan and it says to install the device driver.  Iscan says it cannot send commands to the scanner.

What am I missing?
Thanks,
Hugh

Comment: Where did you get this bundle? It should contain a plugin, that doesn't go with all scanner drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Epson Perfection V600 Photo Scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309307/epson-perfection-v600-photo-scanner)

Answer (score 3):

I have an Epson ME Office 620F. Imagescan is what I have been using so far. But the following steps will help in installing any package that depends on libsane instead of libsane1(included in Ubuntu 17.10)

1. Enable "Pre-release updates(artful-proposed)
2. Update sources
3. Install: libsane1 (e.g. 1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu2.1) & copy
   libsane-epkowa files to x86-64 libs:

   `sudo cp /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa.* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/`
4. Install your dirver bundle, for instance in my case(ME-620F) iscan-bundle-1.X.X.x64.deb from http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.php?version=1.0.4
   (or your required driver that depends on libsane)
5. edit /etc/udev/rules.d/79-udev-epson.rules

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/79-udev-epson.rules
   ```

   Add the following:

   ```
   # chmod device EPSON group
   ATTRS{manufacturer}=="EPSON", DRIVERS=="usb", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="*", MODE="0777"
   ```
6. Reboot

Thanks to **tanstaafl** on
https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/epson-iscan-und-ubuntu-17-10-geloest/

Comment: After trying many things, this was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You installed a wrong driver for this scanner. It doesn't have a plugin that is needed.

You need to go to the [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule), search for `V600` and download the driver.

The file is called `iscan-gt-x820-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb.tar.gz`.

Comment: Thanks that got the correct driver.  I am a newbie to Ubuntu; trying to escape the poor performance of Win10.

Comment: If the answer is correct, accept it by clicking the check sign at the left.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that iscan-gt-x820-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb.tar.gz is uninstallable in (K)ubuntu 17.10 as it depends on libsane which has been replaced with libsane1, which the installer doesn't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 23.10

As [Pilot6 said](https://askubuntu.com/a/946201/1157209), you need to go to the [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule), search for your model and download the driver.

The drivers depend on `libsane`. However, in Ubuntu 23.10, the package `libsane` is missing. A workaround is to download and install the `libsane` package from another Ubuntu release. In the example below, I am using [`libsane` from Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/libsane) for `amd64` architecture. You also have to install `libsane1` package, because `libsane` depends on it.

```
sudo apt install libsane1
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sane-backends/libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb
```

After that, you should be able to install your drivers with Running `sudo ./install.sh` from within the driver's directory.

#### Related:

- [Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic: Unable to locate package libsane](https://askubuntu.com/a/1493881/1157209)