# Epson Perfection 3170 Photo 17.10

Tags: drivers, 17.10, scanner, epson, sane

I cannot get my scanner to work on Ubuntu 17.10

I followed the steps here:
[Running a epson Scanner perfection 3170](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49389/running-a-epson-scanner-perfection-3170)

`sudo sane-find-scanner`
says

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0116 [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:001:006
```

but `scanimage -L` or `sudo scanimage -L` says;

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

Can anyone advise how to diagnose?

Same problem exists in the latest openSUSE Leap 42.3 (I run dual boot).

When I used openSUSE 12.3 and Ubuntu 10 this scanner worked 'out of the box'. What has changed since?

Answer (score 0):

Although this talks about a different scanner, this may be your problem.  See [Device driver for Epson V600 Perfection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946198/device-driver-for-epson-v600-perfection)[Device driver for Epson V600 Perfection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946198/device-driver-for-epson-v600-perfection)

The key point made there is that there is a dependency on libsane but libsane has been replaced with libsane1

I have not yet gotten my scanner working. I am waiting either for Epson to fix it on their end or to see what happens when I install Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I do not understand any of that. How can I find out why this scanner worked before and not now? Are there any log files to see why the scanner is seen in sane but not scanimage?