# Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic -> Epson iscan > Unable to locate package libsane

Tags: scanner, epson, 23.10

I tried to install the drivers for my scanners from Epson: V300 and XP-520

I downloaded:

- `iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz` (http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.php?version=2.30.4)
- `iscan-gt-f720-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz` (http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-f720&version=2.30.4)

Tried to run `sudo ./install.sh` but for both packages I get the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libsane
```

Comment: What is `install.sh`?

Comment: The `iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb` is folder, containing an `install.sh` to install the drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in 2017, someone decided to rename `libsane` to `libsane1`. Currently, `libsane` is just used for backwards compatibility purposes. It has no files itself. It does nothing else but depend on `libsane1`. However, the `libsane` package is not available in Ubuntu 23.10 and there is high probability, we wouldn't see it it future releases.

For your driver to work, first you will have to install the `libsane1` package. And the workaround for `libsane` is to download and install the package from another Ubuntu release. In the example below, I am using [`libsane` from Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/libsane) for `amd64` architecture and it works. You can download and install it with:

```
sudo apt install libsane1
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sane-backends/libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb
```

I was able to run the `sudo ./install.sh` after that.

#### Related:

- [#1707352 - the change from libsane to libsane1 broke many (all?) 3rd party plug-ins for sane](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1707352)
- [#908681 - libsane1: pointless package rename - Debian Bug report logs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=908681)

Comment: This does not solve the problem. It is still looking for libsane

Comment: Can you update your question with links to the drivers that you downloaded?

Comment: Added the links.

Comment: @bky I updated my answer.

Comment: awesome! thank you very much, this works!